# Foreign Key of Composite Primary Key and Another Attribute

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, mysql-error-1005

The tables of my concern:

```
CREATE TABLE Branch(
    branchID        varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    branchName      varchar(100),
    city            varchar(100),
    phone           varchar(15)
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Theatre(
    theatreID       varchar(5),
    branchID        varchar(5),
    theatreType     varchar(50),
    rowCapacity     INT,
    seatCapacity    INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(branchID) REFERENCES Branch(branchID),
    PRIMARY KEY(theatreID,branchID)
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Day(
    dayID           varchar(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    dayName         varchar(20),
    dayPrice        int
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Price(
    theatreID       varchar(5),
    branchID        varchar(5),
    theatreType     varchar(50),
    moviePrice      INT,
    dayID           varchar(4),
    FOREIGN KEY(theatreID,branchID,theatreType) 
        REFERENCES Theatre(theatreID,branchID,theatreType),
    FOREIGN key(dayID) REFERENCES Day(dayID),
    PRIMARY KEY(branchID,dayID,theatreType)
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

I learnt that foreign key, which references to a table with composite primary key, needs to have all the attributes of said composite primary key.

This means to link table Theatre and Price, I have to add

```
FOREIGN KEY(theatreID,branchID) 
        REFERENCES Theatre(theatreID,branchID)
```

The code still works.

But, if I want to add another foreign key, 'theatreType'. It returns error 1005.

```
    FOREIGN KEY(theatreID,branchID,theatreType) 
        REFERENCES Theatre(theatreID,branchID,theatreType)
```

Where did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key and the referenced key need to have the same structure. If you update the `Theatre` table in the following way, it will work

```
CREATE TABLE Theatre(
    theatreID       varchar(5),
    branchID        varchar(5),
    theatreType     varchar(50),
    rowCapacity     INT,
    seatCapacity    INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(branchID) REFERENCES Branch(branchID),
    PRIMARY KEY(theatreID,branchID,theatreType)
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Does this mean the foreign key can only reference primary key?

Comment: No. It can reference any key that has the same structure.

Comment: What if I don't want to make `theatreType` into primary key? Is it possible?

Comment: The you can add an additional index `KEY key_name (theatreID,branchID,theatreType),`